# using webmock to mock curb Curl::easy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara, curb, webmock

I have a RoR site using curb, and I currently have the line:

```
- password =  Curl::Easy.perform("http://www.dinopass.com/password/simple").body_str
```

I am already including webmock, and I see that it claims that it can mock this case. But I don't see any examples of how it's actually done... I'm testing with cucumber and Capybara in case that matters.

Comment: You did the `disable_net_connect` bit?

Comment: WebMock.disable_net_connect!(:allow_localhost => true) ? Yes, that's already there.